# Do I have to log into an email account when sending emails using python smtplib?

Tags: python, email, anonymous, smtplib

First of all, this question has no malicious purposes. I had asked the same question yesterday in stackoverflow but it was removed. I would like to learn if I have to log into an account when sending emails with attachments using python smtplib module. The reason I don't want to log in to an account is that because there is no account that I can use in my company. Or I can ask my company's IT department to set up an account, but until that I want to write the program code and test it. Please don't remove this question.

Best Regards

Comment: There is demo code at the bottom of the docs that demonstrate what you're after.
http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html

Comment: Faced such situation I started using plain gmail account as a test one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have an account (ie. authenticate to your SMTP server) **if** your company's server is configured to accept mail from certain trusted networks.

Typically SMTP servers consider the internal network as trusted and may accept mail from it
without authentication.